# Unable to store date in Identity DB asp.net core and EF

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Whenever I try to create a new User the CreateAsync throws an exception where the InnerException is:
`"The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."`
This error turned up over 100 similar queries but most of them fairly old and none, as far as I can see, relevant to my situation.
The field in the SQLExpress DB is defined as

```
[DOB] [datetime] NULL,
```

Initially I tried storing a valid 20th century date in the "ApplicationUser" model. The field was defined in the model as:

```
        [Required)]
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
```

I read numerous articles on the cause of this problem and was unable to find a solution so in order to continue development I decided just to ignore it for the time being and set the field to null and carry on. So I changed the definition in `ApplicationUser` to

```
        [Column("DOB",TypeName = "datetime")]
        public Nullable<DateTime> DOB { get; set; }
```

and hardcoded the value in the Controller to set it to `null` ignoring the supplied value. But the problem persists. What can the problem possibly be?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried with fluent api ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Apart from configuring the services in Startup to use SQL and Identity, the only other thing I have created is `ApplicationUser` which extends `IdentityUser`. Everything else is managed by UserManager. I did wonder where the definition files for EF used by Identity were, but I assumed that all happened automagically. Am I supposed to direct where the fields of `ApplicationUser` are stored in the Database? Apart from the date it seems to have done a good job of figuring that out all on its own.

Comment: I mean if you have tried to add configuration for your entity in identity DbContext with fluent api

Comment: I would remove the Column attribute and then generate a migration to let efcore decide what data type to use, it will choose correctly. I would declare at public DateTime? DOB to make it nullable

Comment: I hate to sound dumb but my entire DbContext class is shown below.  
    `public class IdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole, string>`
    `{`
        `public IdentityContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityContext> options)
            : base(options)`
        `{`
        `}`
    `}`

Comment: It's also fairly obvious that I am so dumb I can't even figure out how to properly format code in a comment or even force a new line.

Comment: The issue is type mismatch. DateTime maps to datetime2 in EF Core, while you are using datetime type. This is known to cause issues. See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/325

Comment: Either change column type in database or configure your column in model to use datetime as sql server type (using annotation or fluent API)

Comment: I altered the column in the DB to datetime2(7). It made no difference.  
I mapped the field to datetime2 using the fluent API - no difference. The database column is nullable and the property is defined as `DateTime?` - still no difference. I am POSITIVE now that is is a problem in the EntityFramework Core implementation, but my reeading on GitHub is that they know about the problem but have decided not to fix it. Since this particular field is only a Date of Birth, I changed the database type to 'date' but it still complains about 'datetime2' to 'datetime' conversion.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to travel to Microsoft and find the SQL team and arrange for a public execution. People need to learn to make proper error messages.

Because I was testing and inserting a Date of Birth in the DB I just assumed that the datetime2 to datetime conversion was referring to the DOB field. But, of course, the column affected isn't mentioned in the error message.

As it happened the database had another date in it, JoinDate, which was added by the controller when the account was created and it was THIS field that was the problem. Of course, it was my error - I should have initialized the field, but had the error messaged included the column name I would have fixed it in seconds instead of days.

It's like those error messages that say "Unable to open the specified file" but in which the specified file is never named.

`</rant>`

Comment: You didn't solve my problem. My problem is actually totally unrelated. But I had a good laugh so I'm up-voting this :-)